# Accessing the images folder of Joomla directly

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I want to be able to access some images I have on my Joomla site from another site. e.g. I want to be able to type `<img src="http://www.myjoomladomain/images/imag.jpg">` in a html file on another different site and view the image. It's been telling me I do not have permission to access the folder. please how can I go about it

Comment: Belongs on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 1):

This should normally work, your folder permission or file permissions must be incorrect. This is why you are probably getting this permissions error.

If you have a ftp client like filezilla (or you can use your cPanel) you need to set the correct permission for your images folder or the actually image to ensure that it can be read. You need to ensure that you have read permissions set for both folder and image. 644 is a good permissions setting that you can apply recursively onto your images directory. This should solve your problem.